# SPFX Change the position of a ListView Command Set button in the command bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I created a custom SPFX ListView Command Set button in the command bar which works fine. My only concern is that I don't control his order of appearance in the command bar. My goal is to be able to place it further left or further right as I desire. Also, is there any way to move or hide the microsoft build-in button(Open, Share, Flow, and so on...)?

[image: See Image Here]

Comment: I think we can hide or change the position of a built-in button by JSON formatting
refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Charles Simard,**

You can hide in-built button and add custom button like this,

```
let listDisplayName = "T3";
let listName;
export default class CreditRequestCommandSet extends BaseListViewCommandSet<ICreditRequestCommandSetProperties> {

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    listName = this.context.pageContext.list.title;
    //hide New button
    if (listName === listDisplayName) {
      jQuery("button[name='New']").hide();
    }
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Initialized CreditRequestCommandSet');
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  @override
  public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
    listName = this.context.pageContext.list.title;
    //hide New button
    if (listName === listDisplayName) {
      jQuery("button[name='New']").hide();
    }
    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    compareOneCommand.visible = false;
    if (compareOneCommand) {
      if (listName === listDisplayName) {
        {
          compareOneCommand.visible = true;
        }
        compareOneCommand.visible = event.selectedRows.length === 0;
      }
      else {
        compareOneCommand.visible = false;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
        window.location.href = "www.google.com";
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**
*'New' button is hidden and custom button is visible in below output*
[image]

Regards,
Chandani Prajapati

Comment: Is there any way to move the "New Custom Button" next to "Quick edit" or anywhere I want?

Comment: I also have same requirement but still i didn't find way. But if i will find any way then will let you know. And if this answer is helpful to you then please mark as answer.

Comment: This will not work in all scenarios.. for ex: select an item and unselect.. the "New" button will reappear